# Migration from Glassfish to Wildfly/JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, glassfish, wildfly

I'm trying to run my `.ear` application in **JBoss (wildfly-10.1.0.Final)**.
Previously it was running with **Glassfish 4.1** without any problem.
On JBoss, I succeed to deploy it, but it throws tons of exceptions.

For Example:

```
2017-05-17 13:42:00,911 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-18) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component VersionDao for method public abstract java.util.List com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.dao.VersionDaoLocal.getAllVersions(): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: NamedQuery of name: Version.findAll not found.
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159)

2017-05-17 13:40:03,504 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-110) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component DataAccessFacade for method public abstract java.util.List com.valor.anthillprodashboard.bl.da.DataAccessFacadeLocal.getAllVersions(): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: NamedQuery of name: Version.findAll not found.
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159)
```

In both cases I use **eclipselink** & **MySQL**.

I tried to configure JBoss with the same parameters I have in Glassfish.

Glassfish Config:

- **JDBC Resource:** [image: JDBC Resource]
- **JDBC Connection Pool:** [image: JDBC Connection Pool]

JBoss Config (from standalone.xml):

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/anthillprodashboard" pool-name="mysql_anthillprodashboard_rootPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anthillprodashboard?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>****</user-name>
            <password>****</password>
        </security>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

My Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AnthillProDashboard-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/anthillprodashboard</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The exceptions doesn't make any sense, because same methods worked fine on glassfish.
What could be the cause of these exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, JBoss could not identify the Entities and I had to specify them in the **persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AnthillProDashboard-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/anthillprodashboard</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Build</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Commit</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Project</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.ProjectVersion</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.ProjectVersionPK</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Status</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.TestSet</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.TestSetUpdate</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.TestStatus</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Version</class>
    <class>com.valor.anthillprodashboard.db.entity.Workflow</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```